# Floating placekittens

Tags: html, css, css-float

**The problem:**

I would like to have the kitten appear after the input.

I'm afraid the input has to be floated right and that can't be changed.

Also the **HTML order cannot be changed** because this label is auto generated and injected after my input.

I would also like to keep all 3 of these elements to stay on one line.

[**The Live example:**](http://jsfiddle.net/SVctE/11/)

**The HTML:**

```
<label class="first">Organization : </label>

<input name="organization" id="organization" type="text">

<label class="error" generated="true"><img src="http://placekitten.com/20/30" title="This field is required" ></label>
```

**The CSS:**

```
label.first {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;   
}

label.error {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean on 'stay on one line'? Did you mean no more elements?

Comment: @rickchristie I mean they must be `inline` and not `block`. The elements should appear next to each other and not above or below

Comment: do these three have a container? if so, make it position relative and position these absolutely.

Comment: @EgeOzcan yes position absolute works but breaks in IE8

Comment: it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/SVctE/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning... (if you must) :P

Comment: Quick dirty hack. Fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated: per change of mind over fixed width input,

still have a right margin on the input, then position the kitten in the space - needs a "row" container div

#### [Updated Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/9p49y/)

---

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/nT3AP/)

```
.first {
    float: left;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;    /* enough for kitten */
}

.error {
    float: right;
    right: -230px; /* input width + kitten width + any margin */
    position: relative;
}
```

I did try margins for the .error div too, but IE didn't like it, but the relative positioning seems to do the trick

Comment: That's a nice solution but that fixes the width of the input.

Comment: yes. So it solves the example but I kind of changed my mind about the fixed width input. Solution is good though.

Comment: LOL no worries, changes of mind allowed :) I've added an updated code sample of a positioning method, would have done it earlier but had to go do some work, the positioning method does need a "wrapper" div for the "rows" not sure if you said you had a container or not, if you don't need the kitten pic cropped remove overflow hidden from the row or make the row tall enough to contain the pic

Answer (score 1):

change the order of the placekitten and the input.

Comment: that magically fixes my problem. But I can't change the HTML. Do you have a CSS only solution?

Comment: You could float all left, then they appear in the order you give. Alternatively you might be able to work with display: table*; or use absolute positioning in relative positioning containers, i.e. kitten: right: 0;, input: right: <width of kitten>;, both position: absolute, and set position: relative; on some container div.

Answer (score 0):

Move the placekitten before the input. Also.. why does it need to float right? and you shouldn't really use pseudo selectors like that if you want "legacy" support.

http://jsfiddle.net/SVctE/15/

Comment: What do you mean by pseudo selectors?

Comment: :P hahah! I mean pseudo-classes... sorry.

Comment: umm, still can't see any pseudo-classes.

Comment: Right... this is confusing. On the original snippet Raymos had used `label:first {}` as a css declaration. Hence my reference to pseudo-classes.

Comment: @SkippyChalmers I never did that. It was always `label.first`

Comment: @Raynos - LOL! my mistake then dude. Sorry everyone!

Answer (score 0):

clairesuzy's answer is pretty good, but it does behave oddly when the frame is too small to display the input+box together. Probably not a big issue, but if it is, try this:

Add the following properties to the div.error class:

```
clear:right;
margin-top:-1em;
```

And then add the following to the input element:

```
margin-right:20px;
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/D9vn7/2/)

Comment: well spotted, I had thought about it and a negative right margin on the label (same width as kitten) does it too, as I presume there's a way to clear the floats that we can't see